# SQL Server show all the records while using COUNT()

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I need to create a report for a survey application, The survey form has 10 Questions, Each question has 4 options, the options selected are recorded in the Response table.

As i said each question has 4 options so each question should be displayed 4 times along with its options, if no user selected that option i still need to show that option and show 0 as TotalUsers

```
Select V.[Question] as [Question], O.[Option] AS [Option] , COUNT(R.[OptionId]) AS [TotalUsers]
FROM dbo.[VitalSignQuestions] V
LEFT JOIN dbo.[VitalSurveyOptions] O
ON V.[QuestionId] = O.[QuestionId]
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Response] R
ON R.[OptionId] = O.[OptionId]
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Employee] E
ON R.[EmployeeId] = E.[EmployeeId]
WHERE E.[IsActive] = 1 AND E.[RoleId] = @RoleId
```

Now coming to my issue, this query is giving me the data if there is atleast 1 user who has selected that
option, if there are no users who selected that option still i need to show that Option and show TotalUsers as 0

As i have 10 questions and 4 options for each question my output should have 40 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a subquery to get the count of responses.

The following query will help

```
Select  V.[Question] as [Question], O.[Option] AS [Option] 
        , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.[Response] R WHERE R.[OptionId] = O.[OptionId] ) AS [TotalUsers]
         
FROM    dbo.[VitalSignQuestions] V
LEFT JOIN   dbo.[VitalSurveyOptions] O ON   V.[QuestionId] = O.[QuestionId]
--LEFT JOIN dbo.[Response] R ON R.[OptionId] = O.[OptionId]
--LEFT JOIN dbo.[Employee] E ON R.[EmployeeId] = E.[EmployeeId]
WHERE E.[IsActive] = 1 AND E.[RoleId] = @RoleId
```

You might need to add some more where clauses according to your situation.

**Happy Coding!**